# Problem to compile using User Define Package

Tags: java

I'm studying Java and I decided to code using Notepad++.

Now I'm trying creat my own package structure, but I'm finding some problems.

1-) I have set my CLASSPATH to:

```
;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\htmlconverter.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\projects;
```

`C:\projects` would be my new user defined directory to my packages.

The file structure is:
`C:\projects\study\Lab03` -> for my `classe01.java`

And:
`C:\projects\study`-> for my `classe02.java`

`class01` is coded like this:

```
package study.Lab03;

    public class classe01{
        public void execute(){
            System.out.println("test");
        }

    }
```

and `class02` is:

```
import study.Lab03.*;

    public class classe02{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            classe01 cl01 = new classe01();
            cl01.execute();
        {
    }
```

I'm trying:

```
C:\projects\study\Lab03>javac classe01.java
```

The compilation for classe01 was good.

Then I tried:

```
C:\projects\study>javac classe02.java
```

But I recieve the following error:

[image]

Comment: Try `C:\project>javac study\Lab03\classe01.java` and `C:\project>javac study\Lab03\classe02.java` (ie, move up one directory level).  Java is trying to use the directory structure represented by you package definitions to find what it needs (ie, it's trying to look in `study\Lab03` from your current location (of `C:\project\study`), which means it's looking for `C:\project\study\study\Lab03\class01.class` :/

Answer (score 0):

The `package` statement must match the file hierarchy.

You have `package study.Lab03;` in `classe01.java`, so relative file name from source path must be `study\Lab03\classe01.java`. Since the full path is `C:\projects\study\Lab03\classe01.java`, it means that **CLASSPATH must refer to `C:\projects`**.

You have file `classe02.java` in folder `C:\projects\study`, and we just concluded that the `C:\projects` is the root, the file must contain a `package study;` statement.

It is often best to leave `CLASSPATH` undefined and then either be in the root folder when compiling and running, or use the `-cp` command-line option.

*Note:* Your question seems confused as to whether the root folder is named `C:\project` or `C:\projects`. Adjust as need for whichever name is the connect one.

Comment: You were right about the "project". The correct is "projects".